# Easiest way to access appsetting in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In our ASP.NET Core web app in `appsettings.json` we have

```
"V9": {
"MainApp": {
  "Version": "9.07.32",
```

How do I access `Version` from a class? I want to do something like

```
string version = Configuration["V9:MainApp:Version"]
```

But I get `The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context` with no using statement suggested. I try using `ConfigurationManager` but `ConfigurationManager` is not available in `dnx-core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did in Startup

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv, IHostingEnvironment env) {

       _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

and in ConfigureServices

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

      services.AddSingleton(_ => _config);
```

you may inject where you need the configuration

```
 public SomeControllerOrService(IConfiguration conf, ...
```

and do

```
conf.Get<string>("V9:MainApp:Version");
```

or you may want to follow the options model pattern...

more docs
[here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) and 
[here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5) and
[here](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-5-configuration-and-ioptions)

Comment: In the past we put this stuff in a static class and it was so easy to access with a using statement. I read that it was naughty to put this stuff in a static class and that we should put it in appsettings. All the references I read made it look very clumsy compared with using a static class. That's why I asked was there an easy way. Thank you for your help @vinjenzo. I've accepted your answer but I'll stick with static classes.